# Is "which" a preposition? Because because

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech, language-evolution

Backstory: Back in 2013 the American Dialect Society appointed *because* Word of the Year. People had begun using a new syntax: noun-phrases and adjectives could now follow *because*. [In response](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494) Geoffrey Pullum on the Language Log corrected all dictionaries everywhere and argued that *because* is not a conjunction but a preposition. With this new usage *because* has not changed or added to its part-of-speech. It is simply acting ever more like the preposition that it is.

That's all old news. Recently I saw a similar use of *which*:

> The earth was formless and empty, and darkness was hovering over the surface of the deep, which, ugh. ([Source.](https://medium.com/absurdist/the-bible-written-in-new-york-city-blog-voice-d8aa8341e081#.cxzj3x4j7))

Simply by rules of analogy, would this usage make *which* a preposition as well?

***6/29/17 Edit:**

I've found another [sighting](https://trackchanges.postlight.com/ten-minutes-of-silence-f9baa9d1142f):

> That was it. I walked out (no one clapped, **which**, fair), and for the next half hour I sat in the quiet dark, as three more people took their turns. I peeked through the curtain a few times. One person was lying down. Another was just sitting there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is almost certainly mispunctuated as the answerer says, and thus error-based. Whether or not Professor Pullum speaks for all grammarians is another matter. Elizabeth Cowper, for instance, in _A Concise Introduction to Syntactic Theory: The Government-Binding Approach_ says 'we will adopt the hypothesis ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would disagree and venture that it is actually a contracted form of "to which I say, ugh."

Comment: I don't think it's error-based either.   Whether or not the sentence is correctly punctuated, the question still stands: when used in this way, does it constitute a preposition?   It think it's actually not only a valid question but an interesting one.  Even though the answer is "no" :)

Comment: You've now included the source. As text-speak, it includes non-standard usages; it may possibly be being used as you say. But ... ugh. ELU is concerned with standard, generally accepted and verifiable usage.

Comment: ... As Mitch says on Meta, 'The community has explicitly noted that they should mostly avoid things like neologisms or changes to grammar rules that are proposed to be better (by some criteria), and therefore is not (in general – there are infrequent exceptions to everything) creative. The SE (not just ELU) principles of having mostly answerable non-discussion questions directs us away from making up things or discussing the viability of a change in some rule (these are much too opinion-based and / or broad: two close reasons).' [punctuation tweaked]

Answer (score 1):

No.  In this sentence, it's possible your punctution is incorrect.

The sentence is really:

"The earth was formless and empty, and darkness was hovering over the surface of the deep, which... ugh."

It is a truncated sentence, followed by an expression.   The which was about to be a pronoun (as in "which [the earth and its form] makes me feel sick"), but the speaker failed to finish their sentence and instead uttered an expression of disgust.   This is not the same as "because bacon".

Comment: Good analysis until you call 'which' an about-to-be _conjunction_.

Comment: Can you clarify?  It's my impression that if the sentence were ended "... which makes me feel sick" then 'which' is a conjuction.  Thus ... it is _about to be_ a conjunction, and is _not_ a preposition.   Am I mistaken?   If I had to call it something in it's current form, I'd call it a dangling conjunction.

Comment: As I commented on the question, I disagree. I think it may actually a contraction of "to which I say, ugh". Now, that wouldn't be a preposition either, but I don't think we can so easily call it poor punctuation.

Comment: I think that this is an interesting interpretation of the sentence, and IMHO either could be valid.   In your case, I would argue the punctuation is still wrong.  In that case it is a contraction of "to which I say: ugh".   No comma.    In this case, "to which" is a compound preposition.  I'm not aware of how to describe the use of a word inside a compound preposition, other than to say "in this sentence which is part of a compound preposition".     I also think that you are basically agreeing with my answer ("no") even if you think the explanation is slightly different as to why :D

Comment: Actually, new interpretation. I think it is less personal/subjective than "to which I say ugh." The contraction is all in ugh: "which [is] ugh," where ugh is shorthand for a whole story of response. Really it is the ugh which has changed meaning, not ugh, but because (hypothetically) any word could take ugh's place, it is "which" that needs to account for the change.

Comment: I do agree with you, I think. Perhaps I should have titled the question "What is which" because I am less concerned with it's being a preposition than with understanding it.

Comment: If the sentence ends "... which makes me feel sick" then 'which' is a pronoun: **which**  pron.
...
4. A thing or circumstance that: _He left early, which was wise._ {[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/which)} >>  Collins assumes a missing noun: **which** determiner
...
4. as; and that: used in relative clauses with verb phrases or sentences as their antecedents: he died of cancer, which [_outcome_] is what I predicted. >> but should include 'used as pronoun'.

Comment: Thanks for that Edwin - I never realised which is a pronoun in this context, but it clearly is.  I will fix up my answer.