# Because as a preposition

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, prepositions

Recently, I have seen discussions that state that "because" is always a preposition.  Can someone shed light on this idea?  Thank you.

UPDATE:

The question that prompted me to post this question: [Is "which" a preposition? Because because](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/288447/129806)

I posted this question for several reasons:

1) I have seen this topic come up in comments before.  I don't remember the original posts that led to the comments...perhaps another user can recall.

2) I could not follow all of the reasoning in the referenced article (Language log) and am hoping a user can bring the discussion "down to earth" for the rest of us mortals.

3) Language is not set in stone, and I have the feeling that other words will soon change use.  I think it's important to see how people discuss the words that are changing and to understand these inevitable changes.

4) I think it would help us have a better understanding of ideas such as "preposition" and "Subordinate conjunction" and "conjunction."

Comment: It's a [newly-emerging non-standard usage](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-as-a-preposition). If you're *learning* English, I suggest you avoid it, since the vast majority of native speakers will simply dismiss it as an ignorant error.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's something I see in student writing all the time and know it is incorrect.  I was prompted to ask this question because of another post on SE...http://english.stackexchange.com/q/288447/129806

Comment: @FumbleFingers The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language reassigned the majority of what traditional grammars call subordinating conjunctions to the same family of words as prepositions. Since then it has become a standard analysis. They're clearly the same type of word from the evidence available. In other words *because* is *Aways* a preposition! :)

Comment: @michael_timofeev I think you need to add that the argument is that *because* is *always* a preposition :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers For example, Oxford Modern English Grammar call words like *because* "conjunctive prepositions".

Comment: @michael_timofeev I think you need some example sentences in your question! :-)

Comment: @Araucaria I don't have any.  If you have some that you feel contributes to this question, feel free to add them.   Are they sentences such as "Because lack of money, the trip was canceled."?

Comment: @michael_timofeev Yes, but there's also just normal occurrences such as *I went home because I was tired*. According to CaGEL it's a preposition there too :)

Comment: @Araucaria I'm fine with "because" having dual citizenship or a "wave / particle" nature.  I think I'm interested because it seems that my understanding of "conjunction" and "preposition" need updating and "refining."  In fact, that's why I enjoy grammar so much--because it isn't set in stone like Math...there's room for points of view or reevaluation.

Comment: Why be secretive? ... *Recently, I have seen discussions* .....What examples have you got that *because* is always a preposition? Post a link, cite a passage.  When did it stop being a conjunction?  Why do I feel it's been demoted? Why are grammarians discussing this?!? @Araucaria Yes, examples please!

Comment: @michael_timofeev Can I have a more substantial edit of your question?

Comment: @Araucaria yes, by all means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventionally *because* is considered a conjunction, because it links (or conjoins) two clauses. The argument against its classification as a conjunction is that *because* operate like other subordinating or coordinating conjunctions but does operate like prepositions.

This [post](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494) on the Language Log demonstrates that *because* is not a conjunction by comparing it to *that* (subordinating conjunction) and *and* (coordinating conjunction). I summarize the argument below.

**Typical subordinating conjunction:** *that*

- *That* can be omitted from a sentence and the sentence's meaning generally remains the same.
- The clauses cannot be rearranged and maintain meaning: "[clause 1] that [clause 2]" != "that [clause 2], [clause 1]".
- Complements follow *that*.
- **If *because* is omitted from a sentence the meaning does not remain the same.**
- **With *because* the clauses can be rearranged.**
- **Adjuncts generally follow *because*.**

**Typical coordinating conjunction:** *and*

- The two clauses joined by *and* can be rearranged and the meaning stays the same.
- *And* cannot start a sentence.
- **Rearranging the clauses changes the meaning with *because*.**
- ***Because* can start a sentence.**

*Because* does not act like conjunctions, and thus is not a conjunction. It does, however, act like prepositions.

Prepositions can introduce noun-phrases, clauses, preposition phrases, and nothing, depending on the preposition. *Because* has long introduced clauses and preposition phrases (with of) and more recently also introduces noun-phrases.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40707/discussion-on-answer-by-unrelated-because-as-a-preposition).

Comment: *And* because is a preposition. The people ask me how. How did I live my life before. I tell them I don't know. *And* yes, I know how lonely life must be.  Because because is a preposition, you see.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite correct, and has been accepted by the Authorities. 
[The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) has voted *because* into the Ancient and Honourable Order of Prepositions; *because of* thus becomes optional usage.

The preposition *because* was the American Dialect Society's 2013 [Word of the Year](http://www.americandialect.org/because-is-the-2013-word-of-the-year).
Because English, after all.

Comment: How long do you think it would take for major dictionaries such as Oxford, Merriam-Webster, etc. to follow suit? Is "since" a preposition if I say "since you", "since English", "since tired", "since useful"? I saw so many flaws in the article that it actually surprised me.

Comment: I think OP wants to know whether *because* is *always* a preposition.

Comment: This is a *quality* answer, but I can't help thinking the specific quality is [*tongue-in-cheekiness*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tongue-in-cheekiness%22) (Because sceptical of linguistic authorities commonly referenced using the definite article! :)

Answer (score 1):

This usage is probably an artifact of texting.  'Because' is still a conjunction, but people are eliding the hell out of their sentences because [they] [are] too busy.